# Надо ли закрывать файл после чтения и записи .xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

Надо ли закрывать доступ к файлу после чтения, записи файлов .xlsx, как по аналогии с чтением текстовых файлов через `file handle`?

Открываю excel:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'expru1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, 'Лист1', header=None)
```

Необходимы ли дальше какие-либо действия, если сам файл 'expru1.xlsx' больше не нужен? Или можно работать с данными дальше?

Тот же самый вопрос - что делаем после записи файла:

```
df.to_excel('C:\\Users\\guzairovt\\forecast.xlsx', index=False)
```

Конец скрипта, или надо как-то закрывать доступ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того как команда `pd.read_excel(filename)` отработает и вернет прочитанный DataFrame `filename` будет автоматически закрыт.

Тоже самое происходит после того как отработает команда `df.to_excel(...)`.

Более того если вы хотите записать сразу несколько Excel листов (`sheets`), то делать это надо [так](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

> if you wish to write to more than one sheet in the workbook, it is
>   necessary to specify an ExcelWriter object:

```
>>> df2 = df1.copy()
>>> with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  # doctest: +SKIP
...     df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
...     df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```